# Find the probability that she selects and watches the last episode last

Tags: probability

the problem is “Jenn recorded 9 episodes in 9 dvds. However, she can only watch 4 of them at one time. Supposed she selects 4 of dvds randomly.  What is the probability that she selects and watches the last episode last?”

The answer 1/9 gets me unsure...

Answer (score 0):

I hope you’ll agree that the probability will be the same whether she picks four discs simultaneously and then arranges them, or pulls them at random one at at time, or even selects them one at a time in reverse order from how she’s going to watch them. Based on that last scenario, then, the probability you’re trying to compute is equal to the probability of simply drawing the last episode out of a pile of all nine discs, which is...?

Comment: I come up with this one (8!*1)/9! with 8! ways to stack discs up and one is for the last episode ending up as the 4th; and 9! is for shuffling 9 of them around...

Comment: @Julia Yes, and what does that simplify to? Alternatively, you could imagine filling that fourth slot in the stack first, and there are only $9$ equiprobable ways to fill it.

Comment: @Julia I’ve added a third way of selecting the episodes to watch that I hope makes it even more obvious why the probability is $1/9$.

Comment: I see. I thought 1/9 is the wrong answer but turn out it's correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. It also sounds intuitive given that each of the 9 DVDs would have $\frac{1}{9}$ probability which would add up to 1.